# pierdo registros al usar Include()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

estoy teniendo un problema bastante extraño.
tengo la siguiente línea de código:

```
var ciudades= Context.Ciudades.Include(x=>x.Estado).Where(x=>!x.Eliminado).ToList();
```

pareciera que está todo bien, pero por alguna razón, al usar el `Include(x=>x.Estado)`, el último registro de la tabla ciudad ya no retorna, y no me explico el porqué. si añado un registro nuevo a la tabla, el registro que no se ve ahora, aparece, y persiste en que el útlimo registro de la tabla no lo recibo al hacer el include.
anexo todo el código que considero que es útil para esto

CiudadEntity:

```
public class CiudadEntity
    {
        public int IDCiudad { get; set; }
        public int IDEstado { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public bool Eliminado { get; set; }
        public EstadoEntity Estado { get; set; }
        [ScriptIgnore]
        public List<SucursalEntity> Sucursales { get; set; }
        public List<ContactoEntity> Contactos { get; set; }
    }
```

EstadoEntity:

```
public class EstadoEntity
    {
        public int IDEstado { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public bool Eliminado { get; set; }
        [ScriptIgnore]
        public List<CiudadEntity> CiudadesList { get; set; }
    }
```

CiudadEntityConfiguration:

```
public class CiudadEntityConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CiudadEntity>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CiudadEntity> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(x => x.IDCiudad);
            builder.Property(x => x.IDCiudad).UseIdentityColumn().HasColumnName("IDCiudad");
            builder.Property(x => x.IDEstado).HasColumnName("IDEstado");
            builder.Property(x => x.Nombre).HasMaxLength(100).HasColumnName("Nombre");
            builder.Property(x => x.Eliminado).HasColumnName("Eliminado");
            builder.ToTable("Ciudad");
        }
    }
```

EstadoEntityConfiguration:

```
public class EstadoEntityConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<EstadoEntity>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<EstadoEntity> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(x => x.IDEstado);
            builder.Property(x => x.IDEstado).UseIdentityColumn().HasColumnName("IDEstado");
            builder.Property(x => x.Nombre).HasMaxLength(100).HasColumnName("Nombre");
            builder.Property(x => x.Eliminado).HasColumnName("Eliminado");
            builder.HasMany(x => x.CiudadesList).WithOne(x => x.Estado).HasForeignKey(x => x.IDCiudad);
            builder.ToTable("Estado");
        }
    }
```

Como dato extra, al principio pensé que era por la etiqueta `[ScriptIgnore]` pero no fué eso, intenté cambiando el nombre de la variable Estado en la Clase CiudadEntity, y tampoco funcionó, no sé que más pueda ser.

Anexo resultado de sql de la información, para mostrarles que sí está correcta ahí. es un join entre ciudad y estado:

```
IDCiudad    NombreCiudad                                                                                         IDEstado_Ciudad IDEstado    NombreEstado
----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------- ----------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           Mérida                                                                                               1               1           Yucatán
4           Ciudad Caucel                                                                                        1               1           Yucatán
5           Chetumal                                                                                             4               4           Quintana Roo
```